# Trouble connecting data to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to find out why my PHP code won't allow me to store the info in MySQL when I click the submit button. Can someone tell me whats wrong with the code below?

I want to get it to the point where users submit their registration form and their info can get moved over to a MySQL database. Then, I want the users to be taken to my index.html file.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

```
<?php 

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$mysql_database = "21st";
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Could not connect database");
        mysqli_select_db($conn, $mysql_database) or die("Could not select database");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];

if ($password == $password2)    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO members (username, email, password) VALUES ('$userrname','$email','$password')";
} else  {
    echo "Your passwords must match";
}
?>
```

Comment: You don't actually execute your query. But if you did, you'd be wide open to sql injections anyway so it's probably best that you don't.

Comment: ...plus, this `'$userrname'` should be changed. Check your spelling and don't store passwords in plain text. You're open to a major dose of SQL injection. Do **not** use this code unless for internal purposes only or for pure learning.

Comment: So, is your problem connecting to MySQL (as hinted in your title)? Or just that fact no query is ever executed as noted in comment above?

Comment: When in development, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: Yea I know quite a bit of it is incorrect, which is why I'm here. Still learning. And the problem is that the query is never executed. I can connect to SQL just fine.

Comment: All you need to do is this 
`$sql = ($conn, "INSERT INTO members (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username','$email','$password')");` problem ***solved.***

Comment: [50 thousand results for similar login scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+login). Piece it together.

Answer (score -1):

Try this using [`mysqli_query`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) to actually run the query. When you set `$sql` all that did was set a variable named `$sql` to the query. Also note you set the variable `$userrname` in the query when it should be `$username` as set from the `$_POST` directly above. My adjusted version of your code below:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$mysql_database = "21st";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Could not connect database");
mysqli_select_db($conn, $mysql_database) or die("Could not select database");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];

if ($password === $password2) {

  // Set the query.
  $sql = "INSERT INTO members (username, email, password)"
       . " VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
       ;

  // Bind the values to the query.
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, 'sss', $username, $email, $password);

  // Run the query.
  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  
  // Free the result set.
  mysqli_free_result($sql);
        
  // Close the connection.
  mysqli_close($conn);

}
else {
  echo "Your passwords must match";
}
```

Comment: This may solve the OP's problem, but it shouldn't be used and for so many reasons.

Comment: True, yet I always get downvoted when I don't point out major issues. If you do get one, rest assured it will not have come from me, just saying. ;-)