# Can't figure out why my query won't go through

Tags: php, registration

Been workin' on this all day now, visited many forums and have taken a lot of advice but something still seems to be wrong.

I'm trying to submit the query through to SQL once all the proper user info has been entered, and then redirect the user back to index.html as a 'logged in' user once this has been done.

Here is the code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
//setup database connection
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$mysql_database = "21st";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Could not connect database");
        mysqli_select_db($conn, $mysql_database) or die("Could not select database");

//get user info     
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];
//if passwords are equal and longer than 5 characters, and username is longer than 4 characters
if ($password != $password2) || (strlen($username)) < 4 || (strlen($password < 5))  {
        header('Location: index.html');
} else  {
        //encrypt passwords
        $password = md5($password);
        $password2 = md5($password2);
        //sanitize email
        $sanitized_email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        //insert query into database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO members (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username','$email','$password')"; 
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        //redirect user to index.html once all is completed
        header('Location: index.html');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: md5 is not secure for passwords, [see this eg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Comment: Have you checked that the column names in the DB are the same as the column names you specify in the SQL query?

Comment: Why are you MD5ing password 1 & 2 when you already checked to make sure they are the same thing?

Comment: @DanielLisik Reread what I wrote

Comment: but why password2 hashed too

Comment: @Hans sorry, misunderstood you.

Comment: [**You asked this already**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572929/please-help-trouble-connecting-data-to-mysql) yet you've made it even more complicated for yourself this time. Fix the first one, then figure this one out after.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your coding:

```
if ($password != $password2) || (strlen($username)) < 4 || (strlen($password < 5))  {
        header('Location: index.html');
}
```

Should be

```
(strlen($username) < 4)
(strlen($password) < 5)
```

**EDIT**

Your `if else` syntax is incorrect ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php))

The correct code should look like this:

```
if ( ($password != $password2) || (strlen($username) < 4) || (strlen($password) < 5) ) {
     header('Location: index.html');
} else {
        // Handle your false
}
```

Comment: Also add a param to `header('Location: index.html');` to see which header is firing.. ie - `header('Locaiton: index.html?c=1');` and `header('Locaiton: index.html?c=2');`

Comment: Yes, and it will never evaluate to true as it was, so it should not be the case? :)

Comment: But it wont evaluate to false either because there is a syntax error with the whole `if` statement needs `( )` around the entire condition

Comment: Well, you got a point. With all this error reporting stuff I wonder how the OP does not catch the error